# Why do we need setRollbackOnly, not just rollback the transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jta

When I use `@Transactional` in my project, I set timeout to 60 seconds.
But after the process ran more than 60 seconds, the transaction didn't roll back immediately, it just called `setRollbackOnly()` method to mark the transaction as roll back only and when transaction tried to commit it detected the roll back only mark and roll back.

I am wondering why do we need `setRollbackOnly()`? Why don't we just call `rollback()` ?
Is this the design of JTA?

Answer (score 0):

Actually rollback will invoke when something went wrong in current transaction(i.e Some exceptions).
Here you are setting timeout 60 sec manually.

Case 1: If Transaction execute within time, then it commits.

Case 2: If Transaction went wrong due to some exceptions within time, then it will call directly `rollback()`;

Case 3: If transaction not completed within time, it set one flag `setRollbackOnly()`.

After this also transaction will execute, Even transaction successful after 60 sec it won't commit because there is `setRollbackOnly()` flag.